# Using f2py with LAPACK called from inside a module

Tags: python, fortran, fortran90, f2py

I am trying to wrap FORTRAN90 code using f2py by writing the following commands

```
gfortran -c nrt.f90
gfortran -c lu.f90
gfortran -c sqn.f90
gfortran -c csm.f90 -llapack -lblas
gfortran -c pa.f90

f2py -c nrt.f90 lu.f90 sqn.f90 csm.f90 pa.f90 -m p_avg
```

I call the LAPACK function zhegv() inside csm.f90.  Everything compiles, but when I call ipython from the terminal

```
ipython --pylab
```

And then in ipython type

```
from p_avg import pa
```

I see

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-8181d9e1b27d> in <module>()
----> 1 from p_avg import pa

ImportError: ./p_avg.so: undefined symbol: zhegv_
```

Is there something else I need to do to make sure f2py can understand this LAPACK function call?  I see other people have asked about using f2py directly with LAPACK modules, but here I am using a LAPACK function from within another piece of FORTRAN code.

Thank you.

Update:
When I try the command suggested in the comments by typing the following at the terminal,

```
f2py -L/usr/lib/lapack -llapack -c nrt.f90 lu.f90 sqn.f90 csm.f90 pa.f90 -m p_avg
```

or

```
f2py -L/usr/lib/ -llapack -c nrt.f90 lu.f90 sqn.f90 csm.f90 pa.f90 -m p_avg
```

And then typing the following in ipython,

```
from p_avg import pa
```

I get

```
----------------------------------------------------------------    -----------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent    call last)
<ipython-input-1-8181d9e1b27d> in <module>()
----> 1 from p_avg import pa

ImportError: No module named p_avg
```

Comment: Have you seen this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766969/f2py-wrapping-fortran-module-which-makes-use-of-subrouines-distributed-in-diffe) and its answer ? Could you try something like `f2py -L/path/to/lapack -llapack -c nrt.f90 lu.f90 sqn.f90 csm.f90 pa.f90 -m p_avg` ?

Comment: I am in Ubuntu and hopefully put in the correct path to lapack.  Unfortunately, another problem seems to result from that command.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you can indeed write

```
f2py -L/usr/lib/ -llapack -c nrt.f90 lu.f90 sqn.f90 csm.f90 pa.f90 -m p_avg
```

but you need to make sure the lapack development library is installed.  When I only had liblapack3 installed, the above command didn't work.